# Issue with nUnit Test when using Prism for Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xamarin.forms, nunit, prism

I am trying to write unit test using nUnit for Xamarin Forms project. But when I cal the method `await vm.LoadExes();` inside the `Viewmodel`, i am getting the an error:

> The type 'BindableBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Prism, Version=6.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=91a96d2a154366d8'."

```
    public class ExesTests 
    {
        private Mock<IExService> mockExService;
        private Mock<INavigationService> mockNavigationService;
        private Mock<IPageDialogService> mockPageDialogService;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            mockExService = new Mock<IExService>();
            var exes = new List<Ex>()
            {   
                new Ex()
            };
            mockExService.Setup(o => o.GetExes().Result).Returns(exes);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task GetExesTest()
        {           
            var vm = new ExesPageViewModel(mockExService.Object, 
                mockNavigationService.Object, mockPageDialogService.Object);            
            await vm.LoadExes(); // Getting error here

         //Assert here
        }
    }
```

Prism is used in the Xamarin Forms project for MVVM.
The signature for the method in `ViewModel` is

```
internal async Task LoadExes()
{
    //Do something
}
```

Method is marked as `internal` so that it can accessed from Unit test project.

Comment: Did you add a reference to prism in the unit test project?

Comment: @KenTucker Yes. I have already added Prism nuget package to the project.

Comment: JIC, is it the same version?

Comment: @EvX  What is JIC?